JS Regex MatchAll with combination of Comma & Semicolon
I'm having a requirement of js regex should return the object from String.
String: 'A: 100 - 200, B B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C:, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E'
Output:
{
'A': '100 - 200',
'B B': 'Test & Test2, Tes3',
'C': '',
'D': '11 22',
'E': 'E 444,55E'
}

I tried with following regex.
const regexp = /([^:]+): ?([^,]*),? ?/g;

But the output was not correct. Value for E is wrong.
{A: '100 - 200', B B: 'Test & Test2, Tes3', C: '', D: '11 22', E: 'E 444'} 
enter code here


Regex isn’t designed for that

Similar to other answers, in one functional expression:


const input = 'A: 100 - 200, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C: 40, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E'

const result = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(
    input.matchAll(/([^\s,:]+)\s*:\s*([^:]+)(?=,|$)/g), ([, ...pair]) => pair
));

console.log(result);



If speed is important, then use the traditional exec method:


const input = 'A: 100 - 200, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C: 40, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E'

let re = /([^\s,:]+)\s*:\s*([^:]+)(?=,|$)/g, match, result = {};
while (match = re.exec(input)) result[match[1]] = match[2];

console.log(result);




thanks trincot. I need to add the additional conditions for comma & space in the key. (Values is empty for key "C", Comma present in key "A, A")
const input = 'A,A: 100 - 200, B, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C:, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E'
Required Output:
{ "A,A":  "100 - 200", "B, B": "Test & Test2" "C":    "",  "D":    "11 22", "E":    "E 444,55E" }

So that means that there can be no values that have commas, except the last value? Did I understand correctly? If not, how can a comma be correctly be interpreted as belonging to a value and not as a separator?

Note how 'Tes3' would become part of the key 'Tes3, C' in the first input example, yet there you expect it differently... and here in the comment you omit it. what is the rule?

thanks for the reply trincot. I was sorry for my first comments. I need to add the additional conditions for comma, space, empty value in the value(Not in the key). const input = 'AA: 100 - 200, B B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C:, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E'
Required Output: { "AA": "100 - 200", "B B": "Test & Test2" "C": "", "D": "11 22", "E": "E 444,55E" }

What happened with Tes3? Is it to be omitted? If you say that the condition for the comma does not apply to the key, why is there no key "Tes3, C"?

You could split the string and get parts for the object.


const
    string = 'A: 100 - 200, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C: 40, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E',
    parts = string.split(/, (?=[^,]:)/),
    result = Object.fromEntries(parts.map(s => s.match(/([^:]+): (.*)/).slice(1)));

console.log(result);




The regex that you tried ([^:]+): ?([^,]*),? ? also has a match Tes3, C: 40 which is not correct besides the match for E.
You get those matches because this part [^,]* does not match a comma, so it will stop when it encounters the first one.
Also note that when using a pattern like this with negated character classes ([^:]+): ?([^,]*) it can also match just  :
Another version with 2 capture groups:
\b([A-Z]+):\s+([^\s,][^,]*(?:,(?!\s+[A-Z]+:)[^,]*)*)

The regex in parts match:

\b A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
([A-Z]+) Capture group 1, match 1+ chars A-Z
:\s+ Match a colon and 1+ whitespace chars
( Capture group 2

[^\s,][^,]* Match at least 1 non whitespace char other than a comma followed by 0+ chars other than a comma
(?: Non capture group to repeat as a whole

,(?!\s+[A-Z]+:) Match a comma when not directly followed by whitespace chars, 1+ chars A-Z and a colon


[^,]* Match optional characters other than a comma
)* Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it


) Close group 2

See a regex demo


const regex = /\b([A-Z]+):\s+([^\s,][^,]*(?:,(?!\s+[A-Z]+:)[^,]*)*)/g;
const s = 'A: 100 - 200, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C: 40, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E';
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Array.from(
    s.matchAll(regex),
    m => [m[1], m[2]]
  )
);
console.log(result);




You could use some lookahead:


const input = 'A: 100 - 200, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C: 40, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E'

const out = {};
for(const m of input.matchAll(/(?:^|,)\s*(\S+):\s*([^:]+)(?=,\s*\S+:|$)/g)){
  out[m[1]] = m[2];
}

console.log(out);




g is q . . .

Regex will not give perfect solution for this, if input format is very unpredictable like this. Specially for the value of C:. Here is the exact output based on your requirement without regex:


const str = 'A,A: 100 - 200, B, B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C:, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E';

const object = {};
let activeKey = '';
let buffValue = '';

const parts = str.split(/,\s*/);
for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  if (parts[i].includes(':')) {
    if (activeKey) {
      object[activeKey] = buffValue.trim();
    }
    //Spliting to key and value
    const [key, value] = parts[i].split(/:\s*/);
    activeKey = key.trim();
    buffValue = value ? value.trim() : '';
  } else {
    buffValue += ', ' + parts[i];
  }
}

// the last key-value pair
if (activeKey) {
  object[activeKey] = buffValue.trim();
}

console.log(object);




An alternative, where keys should be seperated with comma without space between the letters. i.e., B,B: is OK but B, B: is not.


const input = "A,A: 100 - 200, B,B: Test & Test2, Tes3, C:, D: 11 22, E: E 444,55E";
        
var output= input.replace(/([A-Z,])+?(?=:)/g, '"$&"');
output    = output.replace(/(?<=\:\s).+?(?=,\s\"|$)/g, '"$&"');

console.log(output);



